# find the relation between $A$ and $G$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If A and G ar A.M. and G.M. and $x^2-2Ax+G^2=0$ then find the relation between $A$ and $G$.

The answer is $A>G$ but I couldn't understand why its always true.Please help.

Comment: What is $x$? And $A$ is the average of what variables?

Comment: it is not mentioned in the question thats why i was confused

Comment: Where did you get the question?

Comment: it is in a textbook for standard 11 named K.C Sinha.page 17.34 Q.17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A>G, you can simply show this by considering A-G and you will get it non negative.
Let 'a' and 'b' be your numbers, $A= (a+b)/2$, $G=\sqrt{ab}$ , $A-G = (\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b})^2$, which is always
 non negative.